# How to use "emojione" in Ionic App

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, emoji, emojione

In my Ionic App, I want to use [emojione](http://emojione.com/) for smiley in chat. Unfortunately, I didn't find useful documentation to show how to use [emojione](http://emojione.com/).

Now I want to create a popup that contain all list of smiley and it's related group. **like this:**

[image]

In downloaded files, There are **png sprite** of smiley and it's **css** file, But there isn't any **HTML** file that show the smiley list.

**How can I create this list?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research two days, I didn't find any answer on internet, So, I wrote the list (that contain all of the emoji with it's category) myself and solve the problem.

In downloaded folder at [emojione.com](http://emojione.com), there is some file that I used to create list:

**1. emojione.sprites.css** That contain `background-position` and `classname`

**2. emojione.sprites.png** This is a sprite image of all emoji

**3. emoji.json** Than contain all emoji name,category, unicode and ...

I used [ionic tab](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/) and angular `ng-repeat` and [groupBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) filter in [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

> **angular-filter:** Bunch of useful filters for AngularJS

**Important:** Use `unicode` In `emoji.json` for each emoji `classname` to show emoji in `background` of an element(spite).

**HTML**

```
<div class="emoji-wrapper">

    <div class="tabs">
       <a ng-repeat="(key, value) in emojies | groupBy:'category'" class="tab-item" ng-click="changeTab($index)">
          {{key}}
       </a>
     </div>

     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in emojies | groupBy:'category'" id="{{key}}" ng-show="tabActive[$index]">
         <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="emoji in value">
                 <span class="emojione emojione-{{emoji.unicode}}"></span>
            </li>
         </ul>
     </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.emojies = [];
$scope.tabActive = [];
$scope.tabActive[0] = true;

$http.get("emoji.json").then(function (response) {

    angular.forEach(response.data , function ($elem , $index) {
       $scope.emojies.push($elem);
    });

});

$scope.changeTab = function (index) {
    $scope.tabActive = [];
    $scope.tabActive[index] = true;
};
```